# How to format double to money format? Eg: 3.234,12

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, formatting

I have a string input by the user, this is string is treated to have only numbers, such as: `"3472042"`.

I then convert this string to a double value, but I want it to be formatted as a money value, like: `3.472,042`

Just like DecimalFormat in Java if that helps.

I tried some things with NSNumberFormatter but no luck. Can anyone give me a hand with that?

Used this at first:

```
        NSString *string = txtOtherPower.text;
        NSCharacterSet *removeCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"•€£¥./:;@#$%&*(){}[]!?\\-|_=+\"`'~^abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz' '"];
        string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:removeCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

So that the only acceptable characters are comma `","` and numbers. 
The problem is if I type something like `"2,2,2,2,,,,,1,,2"` then it just won't do anything.
And that messes with my string/number.

I need perfectly formatted money values... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `NSNumberFormatter`, set its style to `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` or `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` (or, if those styles don't work for you, configure it with `setPositiveFormat:`, `setNegativeFormat:` etc.), and then convert the number to a string with `stringFromNumber:`.

See the documentation for this class for details.

Comment: It doesn't format the string exactly like I wanted... It formats "123456789" as "123,456,789" without using dots. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Using a "," is more standard for international business as it is done that way by the US, UK, Japan, and China, so if you don't want to go with that standard you should use NSNumberFormatter's -setLocale: and related methods so it will look correct in each person's country.

Comment: You should respect the user's locale setting (NSNumberFormatter does that automatically) and not format the numbers as you would like them.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, in that case I don't have any more problems. I was just worried that NSNumberFormat would force that locale over the user's. Thank you both for the help!